# Custom Js/Apex button troubles

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to Salesforce development. Basically, I'm branching out from triggers/scheduleable classes. What I'm trying to do is create a custom button that runs a class to "clone" some fields from an account into a new account of a different type. I followed the webservice template pretty closely on the developer guide but I'm getting nowhere. When I click my custom button I get

> "A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was
>   encountered:Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Hopefully someone can see where I'm going wrong and point me in the right direction.
Class:

```
   global with sharing class KA_Clone {  
        webservice static Id Mk_Ka(Account a) {  
        account a2 = New account(Parent = a.Parent, name = a.Parent.Name +'- Key Account',    
          Parent_Account_External_ID__c = a.Parent_Account_External_ID__c, 
          BillingStreet = a.BillingStreet,   
          BillingState = a.BillingState,   
          BillingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode,  
          RecordTypeId = '012F0000001MHUN');  
                insert a2;
                return a2.id;
            }
        }
```

Button Code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}  
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js")}  
var account = sforce.SObject("Account");  
var result = sforce.apex.execute("KA_Clone","Mk_Ka",{a:account});
```

Comment: you need to insert a2 prior to return it's id. so put insert a2 before return a2.id; statement

Comment: I put (back) in the insert command. I'm still receiving the above error on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not correct at different place for example when you write

```
var account = sforce.SObject("Account");
```

It doesn't point to current Account record it will only create a instance of Account object. so in your case you can pass the Account id of current record and query inside your global class method in following way

```
global with sharing class KA_Clone {  
        webservice static Id Mk_Ka(String accId) {  

        //query the data
        Account a = [select id,ParentId,parent.name,Parent_Account_External_ID__c,
        billingstreet,billingstate,billingpostalcode from account where id =: accId];

        account a2 = New account(ParentId = a.ParentId, name = a.Parent.Name +'- Key Account',    
          Parent_Account_External_ID__c = a.Parent_Account_External_ID__c, 
          BillingStreet = a.BillingStreet,   
          BillingState = a.BillingState,   
          BillingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode,  
          RecordTypeId = '012F0000001MHUN'); 
          insert a2; 
                return a2.id;
            }
        }
```

and your button code will update in following way

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}  
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js")}  
var recId= '{!Account.Id }';
var result = sforce.apex.execute("KA_Clone","Mk_Ka",{accId:recId});
alert(result);
```

Comment: I had a hunch that as part of the problem. I'll tinker and get back to you. Thanks!